# Tom tosses a coin until he gets in total either two heads or two tails.

Tags: probability, statistics

Tom tosses a coin until he gets in total either two heads or two tails. The probability to get head at each toss is $p$. Let $X$ denote the number of times Tom tosses his coin. What is $E(X)$?
As the question asks 'in total' situation, my calculation is $E(X)=-2p^2+2p+2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What are the possible values that $X$ can take ? What are the probabilities for each of these values ?

Comment: @user2661923 - the game ends with two heads or two tails in *total*, not consecutive, so it is even more simple than you were thinking. The maximum length of the game is three tosses.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Good catch, my mis-read.  I have deleted my previous comments.

Comment: @YouminHong - I suppose I should confirm that you are correct. The probability of having a third round is $2p(1-p)$, which makes the expectation of the number of rounds to be $2(1 + p -p^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Tom requires at least two tosses. The probability that he does not get neither 2H nor 2T during the first two tosses is $p(1-p)+(1-p)p=2p(1-p)$. But then on the third toss, he definitely will have either 2H or 2T by the pigeonhole principle. Hence
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=3)=2p(1-p),\quad \mathbb{P}(X=2)=1-2p(1-p)
$$
and $\mathbb{E}X=2\times 3p(1-p)+2\times (1-2p(1-p))=2+2p-2p^2$.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X=2)=p^2+(1-p)^2$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=3)=2p(1-p)$

Comment: thanks, corrected.

Comment: Tom requires must toss twice and maybe another time with probability $2p(1-p)$. Thus the expected number of toss is $2+2p(1-p)$